# Phonegap not detecting accurate location

Tags: html, cordova, geolocation

I am using HTML5 Geolocation API in phonegap to precisely detect my location. I am working from India I should ideally be able to see my location i.e. Pune, India but it doesn't do so.

It detects 'San Francisco, CA, USA' as my location. What might be the problem?

Thank you all. Help is highly appreciated.

Let me share the code :)

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is loaded and it is now safe to make calls Cordova methods
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    // onSuccess Callback
    //   This method accepts a `Position` object, which contains
    //   the current GPS coordinates
    //

    var onSuccess = function(position) {
        var lattitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        //Ajax Call
        $.ajax({
               url: 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+lattitude+','+longitude+'&sensor=true',
               success: function(data){
                alert(data.results[0].formatted_address);
               //alert(data.results[1].formatted_address);
               },
               error: function(data){
               alert('error');
               }
               });//Ajax call ends
    };

    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '+ error.code + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}
```

Comment: Are you getting this from the simulator? If so that's your issue - the simulator has a static location set to SF.

Comment: Also, FYI, Geolocation is not part of HTML5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the iOS simulator you will always get SF as the location as it has a static location setting. You can however use this nifty tool to emulate in browser and it will allow you to mess with location settings and more.

http://emulate.phonegap.com/

Comment: Thanks Drew. Let me give it a try.

Comment: @VinodSobale that should help you out - not sure why you were downvoted - this is a good question and isn't covered a lot else where.

Comment: @ Drew Dahlman ohh..yes. I figured this would be very specific question to ask. Anyway. Thanks to you.

Comment: @ Drew Dahlman Perhaps, Because I mentioned I am doing this from India